# Transformers - Why more coils in second coil causes more voltage

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, voltage, inductance

I am learning about magnetic induction and transformers.

1. I have `coil1` which uses AC to create an oscillating magnetic field.
2. I have `coil2` which has a voltage applied to it based on the magnetic
   field from `coil1`.

I just heard that if you have more coils in `coil2` (the coil dependent on the oscillating magnetic field) you get a bigger voltage and this seems counter intuitive because:

1. voltage is based on pressure and that pressure is coming from `coil1`
   so how can it be bigger?
2. wouldn't more electrons present in `coil2` cause more resistance and
   thus make the voltage smaller?

How is it that with more coils you get a bigger voltage?

Comment: Thought: what should happen if you replace a single 100-coil inductor with 100 separate 1-coil "inductors" connected in series? What happens with voltage when you connect dipoles in series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on Jan Dvorak's comment:

When you change the magnetic field inside a loop, an emf (electromotive force) will be generated. Now if you have two loops, each of these will experience the same e.m.f. When you put them in series, you have a coil with two loops, or two coils with one loop. No matter which way you look at it the voltage across them should be the same - V + V = 2V.

Notice that this doesn't mean you can get more current: as you pointed out, resistance will go up when you have more turns, but that doesn't matter *unless a current is flowing*. So the tricky thing here is that more turns in the secondary winding of a transformer will increase the voltage, but not the power.

In fact, the opposite happens. When current is allowed to flow in the secondary winding, it will cause a magnetic field that opposes the magnetic field that caused the current in the first place. If you have more turns, then you only need a little bit of current to create the opposing magnetic field.

So while the voltage goes up with more turns, the current you can generate goes down - not just because of resistance but because of inductance, or the ability of the coil to generate a magnetic field in response to a current.

The net result is that a transformer cannot generate power out of nothing - in fact they usually have efficiency (power conversion factor) well below 100%, which is in part why they get hot when you use them...

Comment: beautifully explained, although I still don't understand why "more" voltage is generated in the second loop. Is it because there are more electrons and thus more pressure?

Comment: Each loop generates the same voltage (pressure). But when you put them "in series" it is like putting batteries in series - each increases the voltage a little bit but the way they are wired up the voltages add up. Field lines crossing the wire is what generates the force on the electrons; when there are two wires, the force ("increase in pressure") happens once on each go-around.

Comment: I guess i should rephrase my question. Voltage is created when there is change in the magnetic field, that voltage is generated on the other coil, the one being affected by the magnetic field. Why then, with more turns in the the affected loop, more voltage is created? In other words, why more turns means more pressure in the affected looped coil, to the point where it can duplicate the original voltage?

Comment: I found the solution here: [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/how-do-step-up-transformers-work] Basically it turns a high current into more voltage as it traps more electrons in the area of the loop, creating a step-up transformer with pretty much the same power output as the inducing coil but with different voltage/amps rate.