# Is the magnetic field cancelled out in a transformer?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/153501/213243

In the 3rd paragraph it is said that the magnetic field from the primary windings is cancelled out by the induced current from the secondary windings. What I am confused with is how there would still be a magnetic field at all if they cancel out?

Comment: There won't be a very strong magnetic field in the core when secondary current is allowed to flow. There will be a (relatively) small magnetic field due to leakage inductance. But leakage inductance is another way of describing a situation where the flux from the secondary current doesn't perfectly cancel the flux from the primary current.

Comment: The 3rd paragraph does not say cancels, it says opposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intent of that statement is that the current in the secondary
windings, if there's a good current-carrying load present on the
secondary terminals, acts in the opposite sign to the primary current
in magnetizing the core.

In a so-called current transformer (with the secondary winding 
terminals attached to a near short circuit)  there ought to be  nearly zero net
magnetization of the transformer core.   Nearly, but never exactly.

A superconductor ring, however, completely shields its bore from
slow magnetic flux changes (the only caveat: it isn't perfectly superconducting to AC).